# TS2349 when import lazy-loading in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-lazy-load

I am trying to refactor a React 18 app to use lazy loading as [described in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import):

> The best way to introduce code-splitting into your app is through the
> dynamic import() syntax.

My original code (working):

```
import addMobileAppStartupListeners from './components/listeners/addMobileAppStartupListeners';

const startApp = () => {
  if (isPlatformMobile()) {
   addMobileAppStartupListeners();
  }
  startAccessibilityTestingIfDebug();
};
```

**addMobileAppStartupListeners.tsx**

```
const addMobileAppStartupListeners = () => {
  document.addEventListener(
    'deviceready',
    () => {
      // Method called when tapping on a notification
      PluginPushNotifactions.addListener(
        'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
        (notification: PluginActionPerformed) => {
          debugLog('push registration tapped', notification);
        },
      );
    },
    false,
  );
};

export default addMobileAppStartupListeners;
```

Since this is a default export I thought I could use import:

```
const startApp = () => {
  if (isPlatformMobile()) {
    import('./components/listeners/addMobileAppStartupListeners').then(
      (addMobileAppStartupListeners) => {
        addMobileAppStartupListeners();
      },
    );
  }
  startAccessibilityTestingIfDebug();
};
```

But TypeScript complains:

```
[react-scripts] ERROR in src/index.tsx:41:9
[react-scripts] TS2349: This expression is not callable.
[react-scripts]   Type 'typeof import("/Users/private/d/ionic/src/components/listeners/addMobileAppStartupListeners")' has no call signatures.
```

I don't know how to fix this.  My knowledge of TypeScript is pretty rudimentary.  I think I need to give it the type of the function returned by the import, but I don't know how to do that.

** Environment details***

Typescript 4.9.5

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  // Config files.
  "files": [
    "capacitor.config.ts",
    "ionic.config.json",
    "lingui.config.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src",
    "tests/playwright",
  ],
}
```

Comment: I guess this can be a problem with tsconfig/typescript version. Dynamic imports are available from ts >= 2.4. Also check "module" field in tsconfig.

Comment: @АлексейМартинкевич I'm using TypeScript 4.9.5. I updated the question with my tsconfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may not be obvious from the docs example, is that the result of the dynamic import is the [*module*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#return_value) itself:

> Returns a promise which fulfills to a module namespace object: an object containing all exports from `moduleName`.

So if your module has a default export,  make sure to use the `.default` property to get your actual exported function:

```
import('./components/listeners/addMobileAppStartupListeners').then(
  // Result is the module containing all its exports, including default
  (addMobileAppStartupListeners) => {
    // Here you want the default exported function
    addMobileAppStartupListeners.default();
  }
);
```